# How to achieve PWM (pulse-width modulation) in Python?

Tags: python, simulation, pwm

Currently I'm working on a simulation of BLDC motor.
My model is working. The simulation is achieved in a FOR loop while steps are time increments.

My next goal is the motor speed control which I plan to achieve through PWM.

The problem is I don't know how to achieve PWM in Python. I've searched for solution but all I get are some libraries for Raspberry which have build in PWM.

How can I get PWM by using some standard libraries?

I would like to get function:

```
def PWM(frequency, dutyCycle)
```

The frequency would be 50 kHz.
Problem is that dutyCycle can change in every time step of the simulation.

Answer (score 2):

In your simulation you have probably something like a time line or such.

The PWM is basically achieved by calculating the voltage at a given time.

E. g., if you expect the PWM to be 1 at the start, have an `f` of 50 kHz and a dutyCycle between 0 and 1, your "on" time is 20 µs * `dutyCycle` and your off time is (20 µs * 1-`dutyCycle`).

Your function thus should be something like

```
def PWM(t, frequency, dutyCycle):
    #period = 1 / frequency
    #pt = tt / period
    pt = tt * frequency # "period" time, where 1 unit is 1 period on the "real" time stamp.
    tc = pt - trunc(pt) # cycle time within 1 period. 0..1.
    return 1 if tc < dutyCycle else 0 # where 1 means on and 0 means off
```

If your simulation time is considerably higher than the frequency, you perform a virtual RC filtering and you'll get

```
def PWM(t, frequency, dutyCycle):
    return dutyCycle
```

because that is what a PWM is up to: to provide an easy way to variate a voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I worried about the time steps. My simulation (the main FOR loop) has considerably greater time step that 20µs. For nice resolution I would have to put the time step around 1µs, but that's gonna take a lot of time and memory to calculate (being that simulation lasts for 10 sec).

Comment: @page47250 In this case, you might want to approximate the PWM's signal after filtering, i. e., you virtually extend the PWM with a RC filter. This will give you a signal of `dutyCycle` if you can ignore the ripples. After all, a signal with a dutyCycle will probably be created for "simulating" a variable voltage...